# Blinking text in Emu8086 emulator

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

How do I make the text printed on the console blink. There's a 8086 interrupt that enables blinking but apparently the emulator doesn't support it.

This is the interrupt I am talking about. Is there any other way?

```
mov ax, 1003h
mov bx, 1
int 10h
```

Comment: If memory serves, another way to put a blinking character on screen is to poke a byte value into VGA memory starting at 0xB800:0 with its high bit set. --- But you're right, they might have skipped that feature in the emu.

Answer (score 1):

Blinking or brighting in CGA/VGA textmode is controlled by CRT mode ports, whose number is kept in BIOS variables.
It only concerns colors wich have the most significant bit set and the mode controls whether the background color is bright, or whether it blinks.
For instance `0xE4` (*red on yellow*) will change to *blinking red on brown* when blinking is enabled.

Here are my old TASM macros which manipulate with this ports, perhaps it helps:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;     DisableBlink
;;     Background color is bright instead of flash.
;;     IN:     -
;;     OUT:    AX=?
;;             BX=0
;;             DX=CRT mode select port
MACRO  DisableBlink
       PUSH    DS
       SUB     BX,BX
       MOV     DS,BX
       MOV     DX,[0463h] ; CRTC port
       ADD     DL,4       ; mode select port
       MOV     AL,[0465h] ; old CRT mode
       AND     AL, NOT 20h; diable blink
       OR      AL,09h     ; visible text mode
       OUT     DX,AL      ; CGA,HGA
       MOV     [0465h],AL ; new CRT mode
       MOV     AX,1003h
       INT     10h        ; disable blink EGA
       POP     DS
ENDM

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;     EnableBlink
;;     Background color blinks if attrib. bit 7 is set.
;;     IN:     -
;;     OUT:    AX=?
;;             BX=1
;;     DX=CRT mode select port
MACRO  EnableBlink
       PUSH    DS
       SUB     BX,BX
       MOV     DS,BX
       MOV     DX,[0463h] ; CRT mode port
       ADD     DL,4       ; mode select port
       MOV     AL,[0465h] ; old CRT mode
       OR      AL,29h     ; enable blink
       OUT     DX,AL      ; CGA,HGA
       MOV     [0465h],AL ; new CRT mode
       MOV     AX,1003h
       INC     BL
       INT     10h        ; enable blink EGA
       POP     DS
ENDM
```

I don't know about emu8086 but in DoxBox it works.